# How to get list of top users based on number of answers, questions and both?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Do we have any query to know list of users sorted by total number of answers/questions/posts they contributed on Hinduism SE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1423041) will show users, total posts, questions, answers, tag excerpts and tag wikis.

```
select u.id [User Link]
     , u.reputation
     , u.creationdate
     , count(*) [# posts]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 1 then 1 else null end) [# Questions]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 2 then 1 else null end) [# Answers]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 4 then 1 else null end) [# Excerpts]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 5 then 1 else null end) [# Wiki]
from users u
inner join posts p on p.owneruserid = u.id
where posttypeid in (1,2,4,5)
group by u.id
       , u.reputation
     , u.creationdate
order by [# posts] desc
```

This is what the result looks like today:
[image: SEDE result with users, total post counts]

Please note that this only counts undeleted posts. For deleted posts we lack the owneruserid. See [Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462) for what data is available for deleted posts.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: This is what i wanted.. thanks !

Comment: bdw, is it counting deleted posts too?

Comment: @YDS no, it is not because on the PostsWithDeleted table the owneruserid is null-ed for deleted posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100

Answer (score 8):

I could create those queries with the help of some other queries:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1423034/users-who-contributed-most-posts-qa
- https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1423042/users-who-contributed-most-answers
- https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1423039/users-who-contributed-most-questions

Comment: Good collection